# how to get validator ClientID in client javascriptCode?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i have client javascript code. and i need to disable some validators according to some options. 
i do smth like this:

.ascx file

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID="RangeValidator1" Text="*"  ... />
```

.js code

```
var validator = $get('<%=RangeValidator1.ClientID %>');
ValidatorEnable(validator, false);
```

but the variable validator is always null. why?

thanx in advance

Comment: What does `RangeValidator` render as client-side?  That ID may not mean much.  The control doesn't directly translate to a client-side HTML element.

Comment: try with document.getElementById('<%=RangeValidator1.ClientID %>')

Answer (score 0):

The validator doesn't appear as a control. Therefore you can't access it that way. The validator will be converted to some JS code when rendered :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice article [here](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/) that provides a clean way of using server side id's in your jquery/ javascript. I used it myself once. I do remember it needs some tweaking before you can use it properly.

If I remember it well, the '#' isn't put into the selector in the download-able code.

Answer (score 0):

The validators are in the `Page_Validators` array. Check the source in your browser. You should see each validator created and added to this array in a javascript block.

See [ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) for more information.